# How do I transport one project from one computer to another in Intelliji?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have this project in Intelliji. However, I want to put it on another computer that I own. The computer with the project is windows, but my destination computer is mac. Also, the computer with the project is using windows, but my destination is echlipse. Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: All you need to do is copy-paste the folder in any other computer, open Idea and select the folder.

Comment: Do you know git?

Comment: Learn about source code control management systems, such as git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this YouTube video which explains in depth
[how to use git](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWYqp7iY_Tc&t=1707s).

Basically, you will go to the folder with the project, right click and select (Git Bash here).

Then, you will need to initialise the git by typing the command:

```
git init
```

Then, add the files with:

```
git add .
```

Make your first commit and push the changes to the repository. You just need to pull the repository afterwards on the mac.

OR, you can always try the most basic form of copying a file: use an USB stick